# Question on Theorem 3.114 on page 110 in Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra

[Dual map notation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqtt5.png)
[Theorem 3.114 on page 110 in Linear Algebra Done Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzNqM.png)

Hey everyone, I have a question about this theorem. I understand this theorem provides a way for us to find a linear transformation (Dual map) represented by the transpose of the original matrix representation of T (notation used in Theorem 3.114).
Right now, I am wondering if there is another way to find a linear transformation w/o invoking dual spaces.
Below is my take on finding such linear transformation:
W.L.O.G. m>n
Let $T\in L(V,W)$
Let $\beta=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be the basis of vector space V and $\gamma=\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ be the basis of vector space W
Matrix representation of T transformation $[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}=([T(v_1)]_{\gamma},\dots,[T(v_n)]_{\gamma})=\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
    \vdots\\
a_{m1} & \dots & a_{mn}
  \end{bmatrix}
$
Then we can get transpose matrix $([T]^{\gamma}_{\beta})^{tr}= \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & \dots & a_{m1} \\
    \vdots\\
a_{1n} & \dots & a_{mn}
  \end{bmatrix}
$
Now, I just define $T_{new}:W \rightarrow V$ to be
$T_{new}(w_i)=\sum^{n}_{j=1}a_{ij}v_j$
By the linear map existence theorem, this should work?
Any comments on this approach are appreciated !

Comment: that theorem provides a linear map which is a dual map such matrix representation gonna be equal to the transpose of the original matrix representation of given T. I'm just thinking of another way to achieve the same result aka find a linear transformation such that its matrix reps is the transpose of the original matrix representation of given T

Comment: Well yes, to any matrix corresponds a unique linear transformation, so what you are doing is trivial. The usefulness of the theorem is that the useful map $T'$ has this simple matrix representation.

Comment: ys, thxx @Mason :)

Comment: A lot of things work in finite dimensional spaces that don't work in general linear spaces. However, I think it is useful to understand the finite-dimensional case first, and then abstract. So there is no harm in thinking this way at first; just don't get stuck on looking at it this way. It's better to distinguish between a vector space and its dual, and it's hard to do that if you insist on working with matrices.